# Generate PDF based on a Word document for each data item

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation

There're a **data list** with hundreds of data items (suppose each item is a customer), and a predefined word document as **template**, the requirement is - for each data item, fill corresponding data into template fields, and generate a readonly PDF file as result.

Prefered platform is ASP.NET with C#.

I found two solutions:

1. Change the word document into a PDF form, and use iTextSharp to fill the form fields. But create the PDF form with correct format (font, layout, etc.) is a difficult work, and it needs particular tool and new skill when system user wants to add new template (unless the PDF form is always created by developer).
2. Add text placeholder in the word file, and the program can read word file, replace text, and convert into PDF. But I'm not sure which components should be used.

I'd like to get some advices on this problem. tks.

---

Update 20130416:

After some searching & experiments, my conclusion is below:

1. Client solution: use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word (Office2007+plugin or Office2012) to read data, convert to pdf, etc. But this method running on server side may be unsafe.
2. Server solution:

   - Make PDF form, and use iTextSharp to fill the form fields. The disadvantage has been mentioned above.
   - Make HTML template, and replace field placeholders, and use iTextSharp+XMLWorker to convert HTML to PDF. The difficulty is create the HTML template manually and optimize the PDF effect.
   - MS SharePoint Office Automation Service is a server solution based on MS Office, perhaps this method will be easier, but it needs license and SharePoint server cost.

Finally, I chose the HTML template solution for this request. QED.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to be working directly on a template. Make a copy of the template first, then write to it, then you may convert it to .pdf

Answer (score 0):

For the second option you can use [iTextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) or [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/.net/pdf-component.aspx) which supports the [placeholder replacement](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Replacing+Text+on+a+PlaceHolder) and [generation PDF](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Convert+a+Document+to+PDF), it supports creating files based on templates of MSWord and Openoffice which could be usefull for user who do not want to buy MSWord only to create a template.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use Tx Text Control for ASP.NET. They have a

[mailmerge feature](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/support/documentation/dotnet/n_aspnet_mailmerge.invoice_sample.htm)  that allows you to fill data into a word template.

The merged document can easily be saved as a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, you can use nustache templates, fill them with list data and then use xmlworker from ItextSharp to render to pdf.